# xorg.conf for Ati Radeon X1300 and Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: graphics, ati

Does anyone has a "good" xorg.conf example for the Radeon X1300 on Ubuntu 9.10 ?
Mine works a little slow...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the xorg.file changes should have no influence on the performance. The point is in choosing better drivers. You may want to try out the proprietary driver from ATI, you can enable it in System->Administration->Drivers.